# Call a function inside a hamlet file

Tags: function, haskell, yesod, hamlet

I have writen a small language lookup with a function

```
getValue :: String -> String -> String
getValue lang key = ( 
    head $
    filter ((== key) . head) langData)
    !! getLangIndex lang
```

now i want to call this lookup function inside a hamlet file.

Is this possible and how do i have to change the function to make it callable?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any Haskell expression which is in scope using `#{}` interpolation. Just make sure you function produces something of `ToHTML` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
myhamlet key lang = [hamlet|
    <h1> for key = #{key}, lang = #{lang}, value = #{getValue lang key}
 |]
```

... or in a .hamlet file :

```
    <h1> for key = #{key}, lang = #{lang}, value = #{getValue lang key}
```

(assuming that `key` and `lang` are in scope).